# How to create MySql script какое расширение

Tags: mysql, sql

Хочу сделать скрипт mysql, который при запуске создавал бы бд и таблицы к ней. Хочу сделать все ручками, но не знаю, **под каким расширением** нужно сохранять файлик?
Ну тоесть, содержимое этого файлика - `create table if not exists....` , например

Comment: *под каким расширением нужно сохранять файлик?* Под любым. Хоть вообще без расширения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как файл будет содержать код на языке SQL, то обычно используют расширение `*.sql`.